# Dotnet core with Sqlite: table relationships

Tags: c#, sqlite

I've started a project in dotnet core with a sqlite db. I would like to understand how the relationship between table are working.

Here the context and the tables:

```
public class HallOfFameContext: DbContext
{
    public HallOfFameContext(DbContextOptions<HallOfFameContext> options)
        :base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Joke> Jokes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class Joke
{
    public int JokeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public User Author { get; set; }
    public int Upvotes { get; set; }
    public int Downvotes { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I initialize the database on application start if the database is empty, like that:

```
context.Jokes.AddRange(
    new Joke
    {
        Description = "Perlinpinping",
        Author = new User
        {
            Name = "Claire"
        },
        Downvotes = 9354,
        Upvotes = 0
    },
    new Joke
    {
        Description = "Random Joke",
        Author = new User
        {
            Name = "Robouste"
        },
        Downvotes = 0,
        Upvotes = 78954
    }
);
```

When I check my database, I see that the system is smart enough to add the user in the `User` table and put only the id in the `Joke` table.

[image: Joke table]

[image: User table]

So far so good. The problem now. When I retrieve the joke, the author is null.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Joke> GetJokes()
{
    return _context.Jokes;
}
```

Json result:

```
{"jokeId":1,"description":"Perlinpinping","author":null,"upvotes":0,"downvotes":9354}
```

And when I try to add a new joke using an http post request, I got a `unique constraint` error:

> SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed:
>   Users.UserId'.

Here is the payload request:

```
{author: {userId: 2, name: "Robouste"}, description: "sdfsdfsd"}
```

And the action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostJoke([FromBody] Joke joke)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _context.Jokes.Add(joke);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetJoke", new { id = joke.JokeId }, joke);
}
```

Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong ? I think both problems are linked to the same cause but I can't understand why.

Comment: You should split your question into two question: the loading problem with the null author is a separated one from the `UNIQUE constraint failed` error. To be able to answer the second part you should anyway post your controller action which tries to save the new joke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF Core does not yet support Lazy loading for your relations.

So you need to [eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading) your relation with using the `Include` method:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Joke> GetJokes()
{
    return _context.Jokes.Include(joke => joke.Author);
}
```

Or use [explicit loading.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#explicit-loading)

To fix your update problem you should check out the documentation about working with [disconnected entites](http://%60https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#working-with-graphs%60)

In your scenario the easiest "fix" would be to lookup the author from the database and assign it on the `joke` object before adding to the context:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostJoke([FromBody] Joke joke)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        var author = _context.Find<User>(joke.Author.UserId);
        if (author != null)
        {
            //existing author
            joke.Author = author;
        }
        _context.Jokes.Add(joke);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetJoke", new { id = joke.JokeId }, joke);
    }
```

Comment: wow, thanks, quick and easy. How can I do to post a new joke with an existing user without getting a constraint error ? Should I also do the check manually ?

Comment: It depends on your current code... Normally you should lookup the author by id and you should assign it on the newly created joke object to the Author property.

Comment: I've added the code but I see the point. I should be able to go on from now. I thought those things were automatic. Thank you

Comment: You should check out this section from the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#working-with-graphs